# jQuery search for string - wrap in element

Tags: jquery, search

How can I search for a string on a page, and then wrap the text in an element, say ""?

So for instance I search for the name "Alex" and whenever I find that name, it replaces it with "Alex"?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this:

```
$('*:contains("Alex")').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace('Alex','/"Alex/"'));
});
```